# Notification message from variable from different class

Tags: android

I have this class for a variable:

```
class Facts extends AppCompatActivity{
public void getFact() {
        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        databaseAccess.open();

        String myFact = databaseAccess.getAddress();

        //database connection closed
        databaseAccess.close();
        }
}
```

I would like to pass the string "myFact" to another class as notification message:

```
public class MemoBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        //...Other parts of the code...    
                
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"Notification")
                        .setContentText(Facts.myFact)    
                }
```

How can I pass a string from another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can used Hander or Intent.if used Intent,you can pass variable when you start Receiver.Of cause,you can make a new class as Facts,the variable be static,when you get you need variable value to pass.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).